# How to get signalstrength in TD-SCDMA in android?

Tags: android

I want to get signal strength in 3G networks in android phones, including TD-SCDMA, WCDMA network. But I read the docs and didn't figure out the way to get what I want.
Is there anyone who knows how to get signal strength in TD-SCDMA and WCDMA?